# How can I remove borders from a Windows QML application

Tags: windows, qml, qt4.8

This is similar to question 4799748, but I'd like to remove Windows borders from a QML application, so it starts up without minimise/maximise/close etc.

I guess I need to set the Window flags to Qt.CustomizeWindowHint, but I'm new to QML and can't see how to do that.  The editor auto-completes the Qt.CustomizeWindowHint text, but I can't see how to apply that to the top level window.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Marko Frelih,

It's easy, just put `flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint` inside your ApplicationWindow QML code

Comment: This is current version based answer.

Comment: this should be the solution

Answer (score 7):

You need to set the `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` window flag.  Since QDeclarativeView doesn't have a constructor accepting window flags you will have to set them after creating the view:

```
QDeclarativeView *viewer = new QDeclarativeView(0);
viewer->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
viewer->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));
viewer->show();
```

BTW, if you are using qmlviewer, you can pass `-frameless` to remove the border from its window.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this with pure QML code, i.e. from QML file directly, without C++ side "intervention"?

Answer (score 2):

Use `flags: Qt.WindowFullScreen` it works .

Other options:

> flags : [Qt::WindowFlags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum)

Comment: @ketan, can you please answer below question,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639380/artificial-emboldening-of-bold-fails-for-some-characters-in-qt-5-2-1